# Pointers in array of float

Tags: c, arrays, floating-point

I have some doubts regarding the output of the program.

[This is the picture where I am using %f to print j, *j and a[4]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXDeU.png)

[In this pisture I've used %d to print j, *j and a[4]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8n4c.png)

Here is the code that I've used-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
float a[]={13.24,1.5,1.5,5.4,3.5};
float *j;
j=a;
j=j+4;
printf("%f %f %f\n",j,*j,a[4]);
return 0;
}
```

My doubt is that if I consider j then j represents the address of 3.5 here according to me because at first it was pointing to the base address of a[] and then we added 4 to j. So in case of %d, j should print the address of 3.5. And in case of %f also it should print the address of j. As here I've considered %d so I'm getting a negative value but if I had used %u then I would have got the address of 3.5. But in case of %f why is it printing the value 3.500000 instead of address?

Next moving on to *j, while using %d, why is it printing some garbage value? I mean it should print 3 according to me as I've used %d for a float value(3.5).

Lastly, I don't understand why in case of a[4], 0 is being printed. As a[4] means 3.5 then why is it not printing that?

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: printing `j` with `%f` is undefined behaviour, the output can be garbage.

Comment: [Enable compiler warnings and tread them as errors](https://ideone.com/7WjrSw).

Answer (score 0):

OP

> ... `j` represents the address of 3.5 here according to me because at first it was pointing to the base address of a[] and then we added 4 to j.

Yes, so far so good.

> So in case of %d, j should print the address of 3.5.

No. With `printf()` and `"%d"` the parameter passed should be an `int`, not an `int *` nor a `float *`.  With this ill formed code the result is *undefined behavior* - anything may happen and the rest of code is irrelevant. Enable all warnings to help see this [@n.m.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367263/pointers-in-array-of-float#comment81687431_47367263).

To print a `float *`, cast to `void *` and use `"%p"`.

```
printf("%p\n",(void *) j);
```

> And in case of %f also it should print the address of j.

No, see above.

> As here I've considered %d so I'm getting a negative value but if I had used %u then I would have got the address of 3.5.

Use `"%p"` to print object addresses, not `"%d"`, nor `"%u"`.

> But in case of %f why is it printing the value 3.500000 instead of address?

As mentioned above, the earlier printing used a mis-matched specifier and parameter.  Anything may happen.

Answer (score -1):

You have to be very careful with the typecasting in C, because the language doesn't protect you against errors.

Indeed `j` is a pointer (i.e. contains an address) to a float variable. Normally, you never print a pointer or an address, because this is different on different systems and even on different moments of the day.

If you want to print it anyway, you have to specify it is an `unsigned long long` number and the format to print it with **printf** is **"%llu"** (= percent-L-L-U), not **"%f"** nor anything else. It could happen in the future that long long integers will no longer be big enough to contain an address, and the pointers will become `unsigned long long long`, or something like that. Better not to make any assumption about the implementation of the pointers in C.

Further, both `*j` and `a[4]` are float variables. The only way to print these with **printf** is with the format **"%f"**.

With other words, if you ask to print a variable of a certain type, telling **printf** it is another type, you will get garbage in the output.

Your code could look like this way, v.gr.:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
float a[]={13.24,1.5,1.5,5.4,3.5};
float *j;
j=a;
j=j+4;
printf("%uul %f %f\n",j,*j,a[4]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The proper way to print pointers is to cast them to `const void *` or `void *` and use the format specifier `%p`.

Comment: Why is a[4] giving the value 0 fr both %f and %d?

Comment: `%f` is not the only way to print floating-point numbers. There are also `%g`, `%e`, and `%a`. Additionally, various modifiers are available.

Comment: If you ever **need** to convert a pointer to an integer, include `<stdint.h>` and convert to `uintptr_t`.

Comment: @SGG: When you use an incorrect format specifier, the compiler/program gets confused. Often, it ends up looking in the wrong place for data. E.g., you told it to print an integer, so it took data from an integer register. But you passed a floating-point value, which is in a floating-point register. So the data that is printed is completely wrong; it has nothing to do with the value you passed. And that is only ine example of what can go wrong. You must use a matching format specifier.